# GA not displaying pageView dataLayer event

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager

For some reason Google Analytics only shows the current active page on refresh. Not if I click through the site without refreshing.

If I inspect my website using Google Tagmanager preview I can see the dataLayer push, however it is not visible in Google Analytics..

- [image from dataLayer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKrWg.png)
- [image from GA tag added to GTM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2LmC.png)

Anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: your image only proves that you do send the event to GTM. But do you have any tag defined in the GTM to receive the event data and send to GA?

Comment: @jilykate I have added another image to the post, does this image help?

Comment: in the second picture, this tag is fired for only one trigger, is this trigger listen to pageview event you defined? normally it listen to the page load event not a custom defined event. Here is an article might be help https://www.optimizesmart.com/tracking-virtual-pageviews-google-tag-manager-v2-complete-guide/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you tag you are using the trigger 'all pages',this obey to the dataLayer {'event':'gtm.js'} while i see that you are pushing {'event' : 'Page View'}. If you see the debugger in both case you will see the Pageview as out put, but on the back, they are 2 differents things

The solution is to create a new trigger that obey to the event 'Page View' and use both triggers.

Greetings